# Facebook get profile link after OAuth2 login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I use OAuth2 login through the Facebook social network for users on the website.

Is it still possible to get the certain user's Facebook profile URL after login(for example by `accessToken`) or Facebook hides this information right now(after incidents with data leaks) and it is impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, if the user grants permission.

You need to ask for `user_link` permission on login, and then you can request the `link` field of the user object – that will return a URL that can be used in a browser, to redirect to the actual profile.

This URL contains some form of token, and likely has limited validity - so you should not store those for long-term use, but rather request a “fresh” one when it is needed.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_link

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to know, how long the token URL will live?

Comment: I don’t think Facebook has published that anywhere. But since this change is intended to better protect user data/ privacy, I am pretty sure that they are limited in validity to begin with, and presumably for a rather short time (I’d expect hours, rather than days.)

Comment: Something else to keep in mind, which I am just now seeing in the documentation of the field on the user object: _“The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.”_

Comment: Thanks! Could you please point me to this documentation? It is breaks my application logic :(

Comment: so, there are no other options to get the user profile? After this information right now I think I completely don't understand the purpose of `user_link` permission for OAuth2 login...It looks like completely useless permission.

Comment: According to the following documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_link - `Provide a way for someone who uses your app to visit the Facebook Profile of another person who uses your app, for example, for dating or local listings` So, what is this way? How to provide the other users of my website to be able to access the user(who granted my website with `user_link` permission) Facebook profile page?

Comment: If what the description of the link field says is true, then there currently is no other way. It seems to be a recent addition, I didn’t see that before - guess they might have added it after the recent “hack”, that was based on the “view profile as” functionality. Maybe they decided they don’t want to give out profile links to non-friends any more for that reason, even with the user’s permission.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm going to submit my app for FB review. Will update you here with the results.

Comment: yes, it is working in the way you have described. I got approved for this permission but looks like this permission is completely useless for my application right now