# Facebook graph api get userid from post comment

Tags: facebook, get, comments, uid

i am trying to get user id from the post comment this way

graph.facebook.com/328843224582668_329144074552583?fields=from

```
The result is 
{
  "name": "Napravo Gi Obivam",
  "id": "332078520912222"
}
```

Ok great.
But when i look for this user on facebook like this

```
https://www.facebook.com/332078520912222
```

It shows

```
Sorry, this content isn't available right now
The link you followed may have expired, or the page may only be visible to an audience you're not in.
Go back to the previous page · Go to News Feed · Visit our Help Center
```

What i am doing wrong i just want to get the actual user who commented on post with id 123456 for example. Or to be more specific i want to get all the users commented post with id 123456

thanks

Comment: That is how to get the App Scoped User ID. You ask for the link if you want a link to the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52577611/10283047

Comment: You can not directly call a user profile via their ID any more, Facebook removed this, to better protect user’s privacy. You need to ask the user for permission to link to their profile first now, see mentioned duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure about this. Try username or link field & call https://www.facebook.com/username

```
graph.facebook.com/328843224582668_329144074552583?fields=from{name,id,username,link}
```

This is currently working for pages.
User nodes may not support this. Facebook revoked access.

Check 
[Get "real" profile URL from Facebook Graph API /user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152500/get-real-profile-url-from-facebook-graph-api-user)

Comment: Try posting in facebook support

Comment: So  there is no way to make something like this: David said: "Ok, thats cool" John said: "Yes bro, see you later" from the comments

Comment: For detailed technical questions please use a programming Q&A site such as StackOverflow: 
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com